# FreeBSD ps command: is it possible to change output columns to match Linux format?

Tags: freebsd, ps

In Linux `ps` outputs:

```
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
```

In FreeBSD similar but not the same output can be achieved by `ps -lu` or `ps -ju` commands. The problem with the latter is that it is hard to parse, due to command that can contain spaces being embedded in the middle of the output:

```
UID   PID  PPID  C PRI NI   VSZ  RSS MWCHAN   STAT TT       TIME COMMAND          USER  %CPU %MEM STARTED
```

or

```
USER   PID  PPID  PGID   SID JOBC STAT TT       TIME COMMAND           %CPU %MEM   VSZ  RSS STARTED
```

`man ps` is not very clear, but it contains some information that might mean that the output can be changed. Can anyone explain if this is possible?

Comment: It looks like you have used four different accounts (at least) to ask various questions about FreeBSD today (we don't get many of these, so it's easy to guess it's from the same human). Since none of the accounts is registered, I find it difficult to see how you would accept any of the answers you are getting. I suggest that you register an account properly and then use the contact link at the bottom of a page to request merging of all your unregistered accounts into the registered one.  With a registered account, it's easier for you to follow up with comments etc. and accept/vote on answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention an issue with parsing the `ps` output due to commands possibly having spaces in them, I am assuming that you want something in a column to the right of the `COMMAND` column in the `ps -lu` or `ps -ju` output on FreeBSD.

The only data to the right of the `COMMAND` column that is also in the output of `ps -f` on Linux (not plain `ps` as you say), is the start time of the command.  If this is not what you want, please update your question.

So, assuming you want a command's start time, you may use, e.g.

```bash
ps -opid,start,command
```

... to only get the `PID`, `STARTED`, and `COMMAND` fields on FreeBSD.

Example:

```bash
$ ps -opid,start,command -p $(pgrep -x mosh-server)
 PID STARTED COMMAND
1964 13:06   mosh-server new -c 8 -s -l LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
2059 13:08   mosh-server new -c 8 -s -l LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
```

You may obviously change the order of the fields or add and remove fields as you wish.

See [the `KEYWORDS` section of the `ps(1)` manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps#KEYWORDS) on your FreeBSD system for the list of available fields.

Answer (score -1):

`-o` is a Single Unix Specification standard option for `ps` that lets one control exactly which fields are output.

```
$ /bin/ps -ouid,pid,ppid,lstart,tty,time,args $$
 UID   PID  PPID STARTED                  TTY      TIME COMMAND
1001 40585 40133 Sat 27 May 21:59:32 2023 pts/3 0:00.03 yash -o posix
$
```

The accounting command name, arguments, environment, start time, and a couple of other fields can all contain spaces, in the output of FreeBSD `ps`.
The reality is that this is true for propcps `ps` on Linux-based operating systems as well.
The output of standard `ps` is not machine-parseable in the general case.
It is a human-readable format.

Because I actually wanted machine parseability, I wrote a `ps` whose output *is* machine parseable.
The fields are guaranteed to contain only graphic characters, and be separated by exactly one TAB character.
This is ideal for sending into `awk -F'\t'` amongst other things.
Ironically, that makes it easier to pick and choose which parts of the process table that I want to see, as `awk` can do far more complex filters than `-A`, `-a`, and `-x`.

```
$ ps -ouid,pid,ppid,stime,tty,time,args -p $$
UID     PID     PPID    STIME   TT      TIME    COMMAND
1001    40585   40133   2023-05-27\04021:59:32\040+0100 pts/3   \0400.031421s   yash\040-o\040posix
$
```

And of course I can always pipe it through `unvis` to get the human-readable form, because this is simply one of the FreeBSD `vis` encodings.

```
$ ps -ouid,pid,ppid,stime,tty,time,args -p $$ | unvis
UID     PID     PPID    STIME   TT      TIME    COMMAND
1001    40585   40133   2023-05-27 21:59:32 +0100       pts/3    0.032331s      yash -o posix
$
```

Although what I normally do is run it in a loop in a script, piped through `awk` to pick normally interesting processes, and then into `console-flat-table-viewer`.

## Further reading

- [`ps`](https://jdebp.uk/Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ps.xml). Commands. *nosh Guide*. Jonathan de Boyne Pollard.
- [`console-flat-table-viewer`](https://jdebp.uk/Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/console-flat-table-viewer.xml). Commands. *nosh Guide*. Jonathan de Boyne Pollard.